# Why is my GET request not working? Routing Issue in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, pug

I am working on the Frontend Mentor challenge "Audiophile". I'm making it a full stack application and having some issues rendering pages that are not the home page. I suspect its a router issue, but I have tried troubleshooting and do not see what the issue is.

I'm using PUG as my templating engine.

On my home page, I have a navbar with links. One of these navbar items should link to the url "127.0.0.1:3000/speakers" and render the my other PUG file titled "speakers.pug".

```
a.navbar__link.navbar__link--1(href="#") Home
a.navbar__link.navbar__link--1(href="#") Headphones
a.navbar__link.navbar__link--1(href="/speakers") Speakers
a.navbar__link.navbar__link--1(href="#") Earphones
```

When I click the link, I receive "Cannot  GET /speakers".

My route is below.

App.js `app.get("/", viewRouter)`

viewRouter.js `router.get("/speakers", viewsController.getSpeakers)`

viewController.js

```
exports.getSpeakers = async (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).render("speakers");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect the router you should use the `use()` method from Express. Try the following:

In App.js

```
app.use("/", viewRouter)
```